# MASMでのアセンブリでC言語ソースファイルの外部変数を参照する方法（Visual Studio2017）

Tags: c, assembly

Visual Studio2017を使用しています。
昔作ったx86の32ビット環境で動くプログラムを
x64で動かせるように移植しているのですが、x86側の一部のプログラムは
インラインアセンブラ（__asm）を使用しており、VS2017のx64コンパイラでは
インラインアセンブラが廃止になっているようでした。

そこで、別途*.asmファイル（MASM）を追加して、そこにアセンブリコードを移植しているのですが
C言語ソース側に定義している外部変数をasmファイル側で参照する方法（記述の仕方）がわかりませんでした。

具体的には以下のようなことがやりたいです。

■C言語ソース

```
extern void asm_func(void);
DWORD64 g_dwTest;
void func()
{
    // 引数扱い（rcx,rdx,r8,r9...）とはしない事を前提
    g_dwTest = 1;
    asm_func();
}
```

■ASMソース

```
extern qword g_dwTest    ; みたいなことをやりたい

.code
asm_func proc
    mov rax, g_dwTest
    ret
asm_func endp
end
```

私の調べ方が悪いのかMASMの書き方に関する情報が少なくわからなかったので
わかる方ご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EXTERN g_dwTest:QWORD
PUBLIC asm_func

.CODE
asm_func PROC
    MOV RAX, g_dwTest
    RET
asm_func ENDP
END
```

でコンパイルできました。

---

> MASMの書き方に関する情報が少なく

[Microsoft Macro Assembler Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/microsoft-macro-assembler-reference?view=vs-2017)にディレクティブ等の情報は掲載されていますが、実は32bit版MASMの内容で、64bit版MASMでは使えない機能も多々あり、尚且つ言及されていない点が残念なところです。

Comment: 確かに教えていただいたサイトに記載がありました。
この情報を元に他の部分も移植の参考とさせていただきます。

EXTERN [[langtype]] name [[ (altid) ]] : type [[, [[langtype]] name [[ (altid) ]] : type]] ...

Comment: @que そこを参照し`langtype`に`C`を指定してみたもののエラーにしかなりませんでした。そのため「64bit版MASMでは使えない機能も多々あり」と回答に含めました。

Comment: 補足です。C++とasmファイルを混在させた状態でリンカに掛けると。「エラー LNK2001 外部シンボル "xxx" は未解決です。」が発生しました。結論としてはC++による「名前のマングリング」による作用だったのですが、マングリング自体を知らない人がこれを見て参考にした時、ハマってしまいそうだったので追記しておきます。C++ソースの場合、extern "C" { DWORD_PTR g_dwTest }などでマングリング抑制しないと「?g_dwTest@@3_KA」の様なシンボル名称になってしまいasm側のEXTERNで指定したnameが認識してくれません。かく言う私もmapファイル見るまでハマってしまいました（マングリングの存在自体は知っていたのですが・・）

Comment: @que 質問文には明確に「C言語ソース」と書かれているため、C++言語は考慮する必要がないと判断し言及しませんでした。C++言語のことをC言語と呼ぶべきではありません。

Comment: はい。私も追記コメントを書きながら「C言語ソース」と書いてしまっていたなと思いました。

Comment: @que 結局、質問文の内容は解決していないのでしょうか？ さらなる回答を求めるのであれば、何が必要かを明確にしてください。解決したのであれば回答を承認してください。なお、質問者さんの抱えている課題が解決したかどうかでなく、質問文に答えられているかどうかで判断ください。

Comment: 回答を承認していたつもりがされていませんでした。大変失礼しました。